# One-line callbacks in Backbone.js events object

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-views

In my Backbone view I have an events handler and a callback:

```
events: {
    "click .update": "update"
},

update: function() {
    this.model.fetch();
},
```

However this seems a bit excessive, it'd be much easier if I could just do something like this:

```
events: {
    "click .update": this.model.fetch
}
```

Is there any way to formulate the events object so that I can call the fetch() function without creating another wrapper function for it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [fine manual](http://backbonejs.org/#View-delegateEvents):

> If an **events** hash is not passed directly, uses `this.events` as the source. [...] The callback may be either the name of a method on the view, or a direct function body.

So you can use anonymous functions in `events`:

```
events: {
    "click .update": function() { this.model.fetch() }
}
```

Also, Backbone will use the view as the `this` when calling the function so `this.model` will be the right thing.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/svVsu/